# Computation of Statistical Curvature for a Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, solution-verification, statistical-inference

$\newcommand{\bracket}[1]{\left ( #1 \right )}$
$\newcommand{\curly}[1]{\left \{ #1 \right \} }$
$\newcommand{\squared}[1]{\left [ #1 \right ]}$
$\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}} $

This post is purely about checking my computation .
I am getting a result I am not supposed to get , which means there must be a computation mistake but I really need help finding it . To answer this post, all you need to do is to follow through my calculation and find out the first mistake you see. (Update: the LaTeX newcommand issue and the font issue has been completely resolved.)

Fix positive integer $d$ and real number $\theta$. Define function $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ by setting, for every $x = (x_1, \cdots, x_d)$:

\begin{equation*}
f(x) = C \exp \curly{- \sum_{i=1}^d (x_i-\theta)^4}
\end{equation*}

Here $C$ is a constant such that $f$ becomes a probability density function with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

The integral calculator shows that:

\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp(-x^4)\, dx = \frac{1}{2} \Gamma \bracket{\frac{1}{4}}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^3\exp(-x^4)\,dx = 0
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^2\exp(-x^4)\,dx = \frac{1}{2} \Gamma \bracket{\frac{3}{4}}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^4\exp(-x^4)\, dx = \frac{1}{8} \Gamma \bracket{\frac{1}{4}}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^6\exp(-x^4)\, dx = \frac{3}{8} \Gamma \bracket{\frac{3}{4}}
\end{equation*}

Therefore, $C = \bracket{\frac{1}{2} \Gamma \bracket{\frac{1}{4}}}^{-d}$. Next, define:

\begin{equation*}
l_{\theta}(x) = \ln (C) - \sum_{i=1}^d (x_i-\theta)^4 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\dot{l_{\theta}}(x) = 4 \sum_{i=1}^d (x_i-\theta)^3
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\ddot{l_{\theta}}(x) = - 12 \sum_{i=1}^d (x_i - \theta)^2
\end{equation*}

And we define the matrix:

\begin{equation*}
    M_{\theta} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \mathbb{E}_{\theta} \squared{\dot{l_{\theta}}^2} & \mathbb{E}_{\theta} \squared{\dot{l_{\theta}}\ddot{l_{\theta}}} \\
        \mathbb{E}_{\theta} \squared{\dot{l_{\theta}}\ddot{l_{\theta}}} & \mathbb{E}_{\theta} \squared{\ddot{l_{\theta}}^2} - \iota_{\theta}^2 
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Here $\iota_{\theta} = \mathbb{E}_{\theta} \squared{\dot{l_{\theta}}^2}$.
Finally, the statistical curvature $\gamma_{\theta}$ is defined as:

\begin{equation*}
    \gamma_{\theta} = \sqrt{\frac{\det{M_{\theta}}}{\iota_{\theta}^3}} =
    \sqrt{\frac{\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\squared{\ddot{l_{\theta}}^2}}{\iota_{\theta}^2} 
    - \frac{\mathbb{E}_{\theta}^2\squared{\dot{l_{\theta}} \ddot{l_{\theta}}}}{\iota_{\theta}^3}- 1}
\end{equation*}

Our goal is to compute the curvature for this $f$.
We will be repeatedly using the formula:

\begin{equation*}
\bracket{\sum_{i=1}^da_i}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^da_i^2 + 2\sum_{i=1}^d \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} a_ia_j
\end{equation*}

We have:

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
    & \iota_{\theta} = \mathbb{E}_{\theta} \squared{\dot{l_{\theta}}^2} 
    = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \bracket{4 \sum_{i=1}^d (x_i-\theta)^3}^2 C \exp{- \sum_{i=1}^d (x_i-\theta)^4} dx
    \\ & = 16 C \curly{\sum_{i=1}^d \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} x_i^6 \exp{- \sum_{i=1}^d x_i^4}  dx +
    2 \sum_{i=1}^d \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} x_i^3x_j^3 \exp{- \sum_{i=1}^d x_i^4}  dx }
    \\ & = 16 C d \bracket{\frac{1}{2} \Gamma \bracket{\frac{1}{4}}}^{d-1} \frac{3}{8} \Gamma \bracket{\frac{3}{4}}
    = 12d \bracket{\Gamma \bracket{\frac{1}{4}}}^{-1}\Gamma \bracket{\frac{3}{4}}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}

Clearly, $\mathbb{E}_{\theta} \squared{\dot{l_{\theta}} \ddot{l_{\theta}} } = 0$. Finally:

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        & \mathbb{E}_{\theta} \squared{\ddot{l_{\theta}}^2} =
        \mathbb{E}_{\theta} \squared{ \curly{- 12 \sum_{i=1}^d (x_i - \theta)^2 }^2 }
        \\ & = 144C \curly{\sum_{i=1}^d \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} x_i^4 \exp{-\sum_{i=1}^d x_i^4} dx 
        + 2\sum_{i=1}^d \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} x_i^2x_j^2 \exp{-\sum_{i=1}^d x_i^4} dx}
        \\ & = 144C \curly{d \bracket{\frac{1}{2} \Gamma\bracket{\frac{1}{4}}}^{d-1} \frac{1}{8} \Gamma \bracket{\frac{1}{4}} +
        d(d-1) \bracket{\frac{1}{2} \Gamma\bracket{\frac{1}{4}}}^{d-2} \bracket{\frac{1}{2} \Gamma \bracket{\frac{3}{4}}}^2}
        \\ & = 36d + 144d(d-1) \bracket{\Gamma\bracket{\frac{1}{4}}}^{-2}\bracket{\Gamma\bracket{\frac{3}{4}}}^{2}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}

We see that the last entry is:

\begin{equation*}
    \mathbb{E}_{\theta} \squared{\ddot{l_{\theta}}^2} - \iota_{\theta}^2  
    = 36d - 144d \bracket{\Gamma\bracket{\frac{1}{4}}}^{-2}\bracket{\Gamma\bracket{\frac{3}{4}}}^{2}
\end{equation*}

Now we have a problem. The covariance matrix $M_{\theta}$ is positive-semidefinite.
The statistical curvature should be a real number.
However, my computation shows that this is not the case for $f$.

\begin{equation*}
    M_{\theta} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        12d \bracket{\Gamma \bracket{\frac{1}{4}}}^{-1}\Gamma \bracket{\frac{3}{4}} & 0 \\
        0 &  36d - 144d \bracket{\Gamma\bracket{\frac{1}{4}}}^{-2}\bracket{\Gamma\bracket{\frac{3}{4}}}^{2}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \gamma_{\theta} = \frac{\sqrt{\bracket{\Gamma \bracket{\frac{1}{4}}}^2 - 4 \bracket{\Gamma \bracket{\frac{3}{4}}}^2}}
    {2 \Gamma \bracket{\frac{3}{4}}} 
\end{equation*}

What went wrong ?

Comment: I don't see the problem. You wanted a real number, and you got a real number. Why do you think that something went wrong?

Comment: Ah I have found out the problem! If I just google "Gamma function 1/4", it shows a google calculator and it gives Euler's constant multiplied by 1/4 NOT Gamma function evaluated at 1/4. So you are right and there is nothing wrong about the computation. Thank you!